# Spacing для Vertical/Horizontal Layout Group в относительных единицах Unity UI

Tags: unity3d-ui

На сколько я понял (может и не правильно понял), Spacing для Vertical/Horizontal Layout Group задаются в пикселях.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу, чтобы это Spacing было адаптивным, то есть задать его в каких-то относительных единицах(процентах, например). У меня есть пару идей, но может можно сделать все правильно и красиво

Comment: Ну у вас же есть ширина экрана. Вы можете задавать в процентах как **проценты = пиксели / ширина * 100**. Отсюда можно выразить пиксели.

Comment: @МаксимФисман, это я и сам знаю. Я спрашивал, есть ли в самом эдиторе такая возможность.